# Get list of elements with matching id, set theory formula

Tags: set-theory

I have problems describing mathmatically a subset of a set which matches a certain id.

I have a function getTableEntries(T, id).

T is a table which consists of multiple objects X.
Each X contains an Id. I search for a mathmatical description, which returns exactly those Table objects which contain a specif Id.

Here is an example:

T = [[1,a,b,c,d],[1,e,f,g,h],[17,i,j,k,l], [8,m,n,o,p], [4,q,r,s,t]]
id = 1

getTableEntries(T, 1) returning
[[1,a,b,c,d],[1,e,f,g,h]]

I tried expressing it with 
getTableEntries(T, 1):={X|X∈T, y∈X, y = id}

but it seems to be quite wrong.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

So I think your definition {X|X∈T, y∈X, y = id} should work, but is quite wordy. You can I believe simplify it to just {X | X∈T, id∈X}, which is just the set of sets contained in T, and containing your id.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Okay, it seemed to me that this does not make it quite clear that id is a feature on a specific position of a set element. Do you have another way of formulating a formula to it?